# How do I get the amount of custom token transfered in a transaction with @solana/web3.js?

Tags: solana

I want to get the number of custom token that's transfered using trasnsaction signature with @solana/web3.js. How may I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you would use:

```
connection.getTransaction();
```